# Spring Boot Hibernate Update statement takes 7 seconds to persist 10kb entity

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Hibernate persists 1 entity 7 seconds (calculated from time that it takes to run save()). Generated value annotation deleted since i never create new entity but only update existing. No relations for the table so no cascading updates performed. DB is Postgresql, indexed on primary key.

UPD Even saving entity without those two large columns
(just putted there string "abc") it takes same amount of time.

Comment: Can you add some details?  This is very unclear.

Comment: I save 1 entity with crudrepository, this entity does not have any relations. What else do i need to specify? Entity size around 10kb(much less cause i just copied log output and calculated from it). Postgresql is indexed, index is specified in entity.

Comment: What is the entity?  Where does 10kb come from?

Comment: Entity is like usual Client(name, surname etc)
Two fields that give this size are
simple double[300] and Map<String,Double> map size isn't bigger then 100. Both converted to json and saved as string(text) in db.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the id was BigInteger.

Comment: And how exactly is that a problem?

Comment: i have no idea, but that what was causing the long save time, i changed it to Long and it works fine.